# Parse como serviço de backend

Tags: android, parse.com

É a primeira vez que estou utilizando `Parse` em um projeto, estou passando por um problema um tanto quanto complicado.
Tenho que manter os dados do meu usuário offline, esse usuário tem um `arraylist` como atributo.

O problema é o seguinte: quando utilizo `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` o parser faz uma espécie de cash do array, não permitindo atualizá-lo, mesmo com o dado existente na tabela no Parse.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?